# NoMatchReverse al querer obtener id con Django

Tags: html, python, django, backend, django-urls

Estoy haciendo un CRUD y al querer obtener el id de alguno de los elementos de mi lista para tener una vista única para cada elemento y así poder actualizarlo, me da el error ya mencionado en el título (Reverse for 'actualizar_visor' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['actualizar_visor/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']), cabe resaltar que esto únicamente sucede cuando quiero entrar a la vista del CRUD donde está el botón de "Actualizar" ya que si intento entrar a la vista directamente escribiendo en la URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/actualizar_visor/5 (Siendo que este 5 es el id, pero podría ser cualquier id de mi modelo)/" entra a la vista sin ningún problema

Código del modelo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Visor(models.Model):
    id_visor = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + '- de ' + self.user.username
```

Código de views

```
def visores(request):
    visores = Visor.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Visores.html', {
        'visores': visores
    })

    def actualizar_visor(request, id):
        id = get_object_or_404(Visor, pk=id)
        return render(request, 'actualizar_visor.html', {
            'form': VisorForm,
            "id": id
        })
```

Código del path en la url:

```
path('actualizar_visor/<int:id>/', views.actualizar_visor, name='actualizar_visor'),
```

Código de jinja en mi html para redireccionar a la vista del formulario de actualización:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'style/home.css' %}" />
    <title>Visores</title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden">
      <div class="row">
        {% include 'layouts/menu.html' %}
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto text-center" style="height: auto">
          <table
            class="table table-dark table-striped col-12"
            style="opacity: 0.9"
          >
            <h1 class="bg-dark" style="margin: 0; color: white; opacity: 0.9">
              Visores
            </h1>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Descripción</td>
                <td>Fecha de creación</td>
                <td>Creado por</td>
                <td>Acción</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for visor in visores %}
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ visor.id_visor }}</td>
                <td>{{ visor.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ visor.descripcion }}</td>
                <td>{{ visor.created }}</td>
                <td>{{ visor.user.username }}</td>
                <td>
                  <a
                    href="{% url 'actualizar_visor' id.id %}"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    style="display:block"
                    >Actualizar</a
                  >
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error al entrar a mi vista de visores:

[image: Error]

Comment: Hola Miguel, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes y agregus tu código como texto, de esa forma evitarás recibir votos negativos, y accederás a mejores respuestas, 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que cambiar lo siguiente en href.

```
    <td>
        <a href="{% url 'actualizar_visor' visor.id_visor %}"
           class="btn btn-primary"
           style="display:block">Actualizar</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
    </td>
```

Comment: Hola Afj, bienvenido, gracias por colaborar,  tu respuesta es solo código, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!